# Radio Button Bootstrap Panel not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/um7m89hp/10/

```
    <div class="piGal pull-right">
    Some image or <br />
    images will go <br />
    over here.
</div>
<div class="panel-group pull-left" id="products">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#products" href="#partnumber1">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="specs">

                            Some Product Title #1<br /> 
                            Some Product Subtitle

                </div>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="partnumber1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
             <div class="list-group">
                 <ul class="list-group">
                     <li class="list-group-item">Some product data</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">Some product data</li>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#products" href="#partnumber2">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="specs">

                        Some Product Title #2 <br />
                        Some Product Subtitle

                </div>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="partnumber2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
             <div class="list-group">
                 <ul class="list-group">
                     <li class="list-group-item">Some product data</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">Some product data</li>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The radio button checks only when the text in the panel is clicked.  If you click directly on the radio button itself or in the border space it will activate the panel but not check the radio button.  Any help on this issue?  I'm trying to keep the formatting with the radio button out to the side of the panel text.

Comment: After running some tests I've determined that bootstrap is doing this. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/um7m89hp/14/). You'll notice that it is true, but becomes false in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, strange behaviour. Something with the BS css on the accordion is my guess. All you need to do is change the trigger for the checking of the radio. I have it on the `shown` event of the collapse.

```
 $(".panel-collapse").on("shown.bs.collapse", function(event) {

     //travel up the DOM to the heading and check the radio
     $(this).prev('.panel-heading').find('input').prop("checked", true);

});
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/um7m89hp/16/

Comment: Edited it. has to be `shown` event. That way the css animation is compete, which is what seems to be causing the issue.